# Why does renderig my equation in Mathematica using MaTeX does not work out?

Tags: formatting, latex, matex

I have some problem with showing this LaTeX input:

```
$ 
F = (x_1  \\lor x_2)  \\land (x_1 \\lor \\overline x_3) \\land (x_2 \\lor x_4) \\land (\\overline x_3 \\lor \\overline x_4) \\land (\\overline x_1 \\lor \\overline x_4)
$
```

I tried using `MaTex["F = (x_1  \\lor x_2)  \\land (x_1 \\lor \\overline x_3) \\land (x_2 \\lor x_4) \\land (\\overline x_3 \\lor \\overline x_4) \\land (\\overline x_1 \\lor \\overline x_4)"]` but it does not work.

Do we have any other solution to show this text in Matematica?

Comment: You have written `MaTex` but it should be `MaTeX`. Using `MaTeX[ ... ]` works out fine. ;-)

Comment: @gwr I did not even notice this until now :) I was wondering for a while why it did not work for OP. I thought it was a version issue or such.

Comment: @Nasser Sometimes we have to also see the trees for the forest. :)

Comment: We should all then blame the Author of the nice package MaTeX for making his package name using mixed **UpperAndLowerCaseLetters** instead of all **lowercaseletters**  (In case Szabolcs reads this, I am just kidding :)

Comment: @Nasser You have a good point actually ... I'd suggest defining `matex = MaTeX` then just use `matex`. Or even shorter, `mt = MaTeX`. It's too late to change the name now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works for me

```
expr="F = (x_1  \\lor x_2)  \\land (x_1 \\lor \\overline x_3) \\land (x_2 \\lor x_4) \\land (\\overline x_3 \\lor \\overline x_4) \\land (\\overline x_1 \\lor \\overline x_4)";
```

And now

```
MaTeX[expr, Magnification -> 2]
```

gives

[image]

Here is full screen shot

[image]

Comment: Many thanks works!